# image instead of checkbox work slow

Tags: javascript, html, performance, checkbox, image

I switched my checkbox with images, but now when I hit one of the checkboxes it takes it 2 second before the checked img appear.

That happened only at the first time when I hit the checkbox, at second etc. it works perfect.

Probably after you hit the checkbox once the img is loaded to the website memory, and then it works smoothly.

Is there is a solution for that?
maybe when the page loaded it can load any optional img for its memory or something like this.

Thanks in advance.

This is my [website](http://doarna.com/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8-%D7%A0%D7%A2/), it's in Hebrew but the content doesn't matter.

Im using Gravity Form, but for this case it doesnt matter.
sample from the code is below and thanks to every body.

```
.DesignCheckBox label {
                   background-repeat: no-repeat;
                   border: 2px solid #DDD;
                           height: 150px!important;
                           font-size: 150%;
                           -moz-border-radius: 20px;
                           -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
                border-radius: 20px; 
                -khtml-border-radius: 20px; 
                                                  }
.DesignCheckBox label:hover {
                   border: 2px solid #000095;
                           background-color:  #F0F7F7;
                           cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;
                                                  }

.HideCheckBox input[type="checkbox"]{display:none!important;}

         li.gchoice_4_1 label {
                       background-image: url(http://doarna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/XCellcom.gif);
                               }

         li.gchoice_4_1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label { 
                       background-image: url(http://doarna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/VCellcom.gif);
                       }

         li.gchoice_4_2 label {
                       background-image: url(http://doarna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/XOrange.gif);
                               }

         li.gchoice_4_2 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label { 
                       background-image: url(http://doarna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/VOrange.gif); 
                       }
```

Comment: I'm taking a look at your site, but it would have been helpful to post up the code you wrote to deal with your checkboxes.

Comment: Preload the images, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I added my code. can You explainme how to preload it? Thanks

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317

Comment: I have lots of images, is there is a way to tell him to preload all the possible images for this page or somthing like that?

Comment: I solved by using 2 img together by this code. in my case it works perfect. Thanks  background-image:url(http://doarna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/VVV.gif),
               url(http://doarna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/XCellcom.gif); [SOLVED]

Answer (score 0):

You are going right, actually a browser loads only those images which are required by the page to be served on page load. Other events when fired only than download the required images and once it is downloaded it will be stored in your browser cache. Which means next time you will  get faster response as the images is on your local machine now.

what i will suggest here is to use display equal to none for hiding images. on page load set set display none for checked image and on click set display to block for checked image.

Give some code if you want the snippets.

Comment: thanks for your help. I edited my question and now it has the code. I didnt understand this part. I will aprciate explanation. Thanks "what i will suggest here is to use display equal to none for hiding images. on page load set set display none for checked image and on click set display to block for checked image."